# Can I have the SO Line Nbr as a Report parameter in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I am able to create a report with parameters for SO OrderType and OrderNbr, but if I try to put the SO LineNbr in as an additional parameter, it doesn't show on the screen when I go to run the report.

Is there a way to parameterize the line number?

Comment: Please add the way you are adding SO LineNbr parameter to the report to the question.

Comment: I started by adding the OrderType, OrderNbr and Line Nbr as View Names: 
=Report.GetFieldSchema('SOLine.OrderType')
=Report.GetFieldSchema('SOLine.OrderNbr,OrderType')
=Report.GetFieldSchema('SOLine.LineNbr,OrderNbr,OrderType')

All type String. None of the three showed up as a parameter.
So I changed OrderType and OrderNbr to View name
=Report.GetFieldSchema('SOOrder.OrderType')
=Report.GetFieldSchema('SOOrder.OrderNbr,OrderType')
and Line Nbr is in as View Name =[SOLine.LineNbr]

Now OrderType and OrderNbr show as parameters but Line Nbr still does not.

Comment: Have you set value to `Prompt` field for the parameter and checked the `Visible` checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For addition of the SOLine.LineNbr to the report as an input parameter you should do the following steps:
1. In the Report Designer open File->Schema Builder->Parameters and add new parameter.
2. Set Name and Prompt to the parameter.
3. Set View Name as the following:`=Report.GetFieldSchema('SOOrder.OrderNbr,OrderType,SOLine.LineNbr')` 
so that the system know that the LineNbr is going after OrderNbr and OrderType.

[image]

Save the Report to the Server. As a result you will get the following:

[image]

Comment: This is great, thank you!

Is there any way of having it be a full selection pop-up that would show the inventory item and qty on the line as well as the line number itself?

Comment: @JuneB I think you can achieve that if you create an additional field with the specific PXSelector attribute and add it as a parameter to the report. The selector here is from the PXSelector on the property of the DAC